# How to work with large datasets in PostgreSQL?

Tags: database, postgresql

I have a table with this structure: id, value, metric, timestamp and with a primary key index on (id, metric, timestamp) columns.
I have incoming data at the rate of 1M per 10 second, so you can imagine that by the end of the day I end up with a large database. I need to downsample the data with the following simple algorithm: get data older than one hour and reduce all records to 1 per 10 minutes for each metric. In order to do that, I implemented java services which once an hour fetches records for the last hour for a specific metric, pick ups those to remove, and generates 1000 DELETE statements in a batch and sends it to postresql.

The way I generate each delete statement is:

```
DELETE FROM TABLE WHERE id = :id, metric = :metric, timestamp = :timestamp;
DELETE FROM TABLE WHERE id = :id, metric = :metric, timestamp = :timestamp;
DELETE FROM TABLE WHERE id = :id, metric = :metric, timestamp = :timestamp;
```

b.c. of the index on 3 columns. When I try to delete by id (it is just a serial field, not primary key), it is slow.

Anyway, I tried to execute my solution and it doesn't catch up. It is really slow to delete the data. I don't want to use PostreSQL stored procedures, b.c. I want more flexibility with the code: use parallel processing etc. Any suggestions how to improve performance? I'm using PostgreSQL 12.

Answer (score 0):

If a delete based on an index is slow, the reason must be that there are foreign keys pointing to the table that are [not properly indexed](https://www.cybertec-postgresql.com/en/index-your-foreign-key/).

Comment: They are not that slow, they take hundred milliseconds to delete 10 000 records on a terabyte table. I think the issue that I'm processing millions records and need to parallel it somehow or not to use DELETE statements. Not sure if any other tools PostreSQL has.

Comment: The size of the table doesn't matter. To get rid of many rows fast, use partitioning and `DROP TABLE`.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered Timescale? Which is a "flavour" of PostgreSQL designed for time series.

Comment: Yes, they are not dealing well with on of the the use-cases I have, in fact the way they designed data handling is is the opposite what I need.